# How to apply one time point twice in geom_smooth()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to plot a huge dataset, which I have separated before and after a policy intervention and also for different countries. The `geom_smooth` of the after period I would like to be a continuous graph, but different in slope for two sections of my data. As I would like to see a short term trend and long term trend after the intervention.

So literally the graph will have a bend in the one year, which will account as the intermediate year of the two trends.

Before I have separated in before and after policy intervention through variable `countrytrend`, and this works fine for the overall before and afterwards trend.

```
gX <- ggplot(df, aes(dfZV3$year, df$y))
gX + geom_jitter(aes(col=countrytrend, size=`Sample size`)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(col=countrytrend), method="lm", se=F)
```

Now I reckon I need some further arguments for `geom_smoth()` to pass on information so two linear approximations will be illustrated.

However I would like to stick to same line color and such and neither duplicate my data, can any body think of an adequate solution for this?

Edit:I think the oranges dataset from the emmeans package is appropiate: Imagine an intervention during day 3, so completly exclude this and check a trend for sales once for day 4 to 5 and also for day 5 to 6. Idividually for each store. So a bend in trend will be on day 5.

Comment: Hi there, do you have some dummy data available that would illustrate the type of data you're working with, or some visualisation of what you would like your end result to be?

Comment: It's great that you've got an example dataset, but please [edit] the question to use that data

Comment: Your style of coding indicates that you are not yet familiar with how ggplot2 works.you don't want `$` notation within the  `aes()` assignment; it simply draws from whatever data frame you declare. Also, `col` isn't an aesthetic; you probably mean to write "color". Also, if you're mapping `Sample size` to the actual size of your points, you put *that* into your aesthetic mapping, not outside of it. Probably easier to do that by converting the name to something without spaces, like "Sample_size"

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like `geom_smooth(aes(color = countrytrend, group = era), method = "lm", se = F)`, where `era` is a variable defining belonging to either before or after intervention. That will make separate smooths for the two periods, but with the same appearance.